# How to Add dynamic textfiled  value on tag using plist

Tags: iphone

want to fetch the value from dynamically created textfield with tag from NSMutableArray....

```
Txt_New_Estimated = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, textPosY , 130, 65)];
Txt_New_Estimated.delegate = self;
Txt_New_Estimated.text=@"";
Txt_New_Estimated.tag = i; 
Txt_New_Estimated.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];//UIControlEventEditingDidEnd
Txt_New_Estimated.placeholder = @"Estimated";
Txt_New_Estimated.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23];
Txt_New_Estimated.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Txt_New_Estimated.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[scrollview addSubview:Txt_New_Estimated];
[textFieldArray addObject:Txt_New_Estimated];
```

how to add value on every index using this line of code ,

[textFieldArray4 addObject: Txt_New_ONU.text];   // value will add zero index only

means only one value will add from this line...

but i want to add unlimited value at zero index in textFieldArray4....

because i use tag on my "Txt_New_ONU" Textfield....

How to do this?Please Give some idea....

Thank You...

Comment: When do you want to fetch the value? Do you have any done button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check Txt_New_Estimated.text value in UITextFieldDelegate.

Take a look here:

[UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

The methods I suggest are:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```